# "Unverifiable code failed policy check" for a closed source assembly

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

I'm attempting to dynamically load some (purchased) assemblies from resource streams in a C# program during an MSI installation routine, but I'm getting "Unverifiable code failed policy check".

I read some tips online about compiling the embedded assembly with /clr:safe, but I don't have that option.  Is there a way to work around this policy check?

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your actual problem - but why hide the assemblies away in the resource stream instead of including them in the msi directly? Even if you only need them at install time, getting the msi engine to deploy them isn't too hard.

Comment: Because I don't want them sticking around visible and in some cases it can be run post-install.

Comment: I know, this is old question.. but still want to see, if this help ?
<trust level="Full|High|Medium|Low|Minimal" originUrl="url"/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to load unverifiable code is from a full trust process (or maybe app domain) with verification disabled.

EDIT: I'm not making this up, [one of the C# language designers said "Unverifiable code requires full trust and is generally to be avoided"](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2005/11/14/why-are-base-class-calls-from-anonymous-delegates-nonverifiable.aspx)

Comment: Wasn't me.  I would like to know too!  Sounds like they would have a better suggestion.  I'll counter it due to the lack of an explanation

Answer (score 3):

Its already too late, but it may help someone.

I've used [Sqlite DLL](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) in my project and when I deployed the code on sandbox environment, I was getting exception (see below)

```
[FileLoadException: Unverifiable code failed policy check. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131402)]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.79.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. Unverifiable code failed policy check. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131402)]
```

I added [trust level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wyts434y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) within system.web in the web.config file and its working fine.

```
<trust level="Full|High|Medium|Low|Minimal" originUrl="url"/>
```

Comment: I've long abandoned the project so I can't test, but cool!   One thing - it seems that `Full|High|Medium|Low|Minimal` is redundant and that `Full` alone includes the others.  (I assume this syntax is performing a bitwise `OR` on the values of the expected enum type.)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be relevant any longer, but I encountered the same issue recently.  If you take the stream and stick it in a temp file, you can then use Assembly.LoadFrom to load the assembly.