# Exception with Resolving assemblies: Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups

Tags: c#, assembly-resolution

I'm embedding required assemblies to my project and resolving them on runtime with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event.

All works okay except [irrKlang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/)'s .net4-wrapper, which throws an exception if i try so;

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups (IAT with more than 2 sections or a TLS section.) (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131019)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadImage(Byte[] rawAssembly, Byte[] rawSymbolStore, Evidence evidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean fIntrospection, SecurityContextSource securityContextSource)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(Byte[] rawAssembly)
   at xyz.Utility.Helpers.AssemblyManager.Resolver(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) in C:\Users\shalafi\Desktop\xyz\trunk\xyz\Utility\Helpers\AssemblyManager.cs:line 55
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
```

Basicly i suspect of CLR [not being able to load mixed mode assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945080/how-do-i-dynamically-load-raw-assemblies-that-contains-unmanaged-codebypassing) with Assembly.Load(byte[]) though i'm not sure.

I was not able to find anything related to the exception message;

> Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups (IAT with more than 2 sections or a TLS section.)

Help appreciated.

Comment: seems this there's no work-around for this: http://books.google.com/books?id=wZoQyVi5f60C&pg=PA150&dq=unverifiable+executable+with+fixups&hl=en&ei=xptaTdzXEMafOpWjjP8L&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=unverifiable%20executable%20with%20fixups&f=false

Comment: Solution is that you change C++ assembly from EXE to DLL! There is probably some linker optimization during EXE loading which is not supported by CLR loader. See: http://zamboch.blogspot.com/2007/11/fileloadexception-when-loading-ccli.html

Comment: c++ assembly i use is already a dll..

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945080/how-do-i-dynamically-load-raw-assemblies-that-contains-unmanaged-codebypassing

Comment: Thank you HuseyinUslu for posting that book page.  Led me to change the CLR mode from normal to pure. resolved my issue!

Comment: I had the same issue, I just changed projects to same platform and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT : The references i posted are not valid anymore, because of outdated external links. Please refer here. 
[How do I dynamically load raw assemblies that contains unmanaged code?(bypassing 'Unverifiable code failed policy check' exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945080/how-do-i-dynamically-load-raw-assemblies-that-contains-unmanaged-codebypassing)

Comment: I found that you can see part of it at the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945080/how-do-i-dynamically-load-raw-assemblies-that-contains-unmanaged-codebypassing

Comment: Microsoft Connect stopped, please fix link @Soundararajan

Comment: @NoahHeber The link is not available and nor the Microsoft Collaborate website has setup the link. After reviewing the post that porges posted has valuable information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is having my version of this problem, here's how I fixed it:

- Create a new project with a different name
- Copy all of your files into the new project (including code)
- Add references to all the files necessary to compile without errors

I really must have messed something up with my references/resources. I was getting this error when trying to load any external .dll from my program.