# Load Embedded Assembly

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I am trying to load an embedded assembly at run-time on a server-side DLL. The assembly I embedded is my own code.

I am getting an Unverifiable code failed policy check error when trying to load the assembly.

Is there any way around this?

Here is the code:

```
    byte[] resource = null;

    using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name))
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            resource = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(resource, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }
    }

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(resource);
```

EDIT:

A bit of a shot in the dark, but I tried to save the DLL to disk first, and load it that way. Here is what I get now: Could not load file or assembly or one of its depenencies. The given assembly or codebase was invalid.

Comment: Found this old question. Maybe it's your case:
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612128/unverifiable-code-failed-policy-check-for-a-closed-source-assembly)

Comment: Do you have tried to check the 'allow unsafe code' in project configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, if anyone stumbles on this post:

-C# will [not allow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2007/04/18/loading-an-assembly-as-a-byte-array.aspx) you to load an assembly from bytes unless you are in a high-security context.

-Funny enough, if you have the permissions to save to file first, and then use `Assembly.Load(filename)` (I made the mistake of using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(filename)`) it will have no problem loading the assembly.